# Why does the program keep getting terminated when I'm copying vector data to another vector?

Tags: c++

This is one of the weirdest things I have ever seen in c++...after running this the program gets terminated. I tracked the source of the issue to the for loop that copies the data of the 1st vector to the 2nd vector, but I can't understand why the program auto terminates after I run it.

```
int main() {
    vector<string> vectorTest;
    vector<string> test;

    vectorTest.push_back("Data");


    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorTest.size(); ++i){ //source of issue
        test[i] = vectorTest[i];
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorTest.size(); ++i){
        cout << vectorTest[i] << "\n";
        cout << test[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply do `test = vectorTest;` to copy the vector

Answer (score 4):

vector `test` contains no items so `test[i]` will be accessing out of bounds. You should've resized this vector to proper size before iterating or used `push_back`.

```
test.resize(vectorTest.size());
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorTest.size(); ++i){ //source of issue
    test[i] = vectorTest[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The vector `test` is empty so accessing `test[i]` is out of bounds and undefined behaviour.

There are a few ways to fix this, one:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorTest.size(); ++i){
    test.push_back(vectorTest[i]);
}
```

Two:

```
test.resize(vectorTest.size());
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vectorTest.size(); ++i){
    test[i] = vectorTest[i];
}
```

And if all you want to do is copy the vector the following is far simpler:

```
test = vectorTest;
```

Or to add all of `vectorTest` to the end of `test`:

```
test.insert( test.end(), vectorTest.begin(), vectorTest.end() );
```